# SPUserCodeSolutionExecutionFailedException

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sandbox-solution

I have a simple sandbox solution with a webpart (which loads data via Linq but thats not the point I think) and everything works fine on my development machine.

When I install this solution on another machine and add the webpart to a page I get the following exception. But I don't know why and what to do and I think its not related to my solution as I can't see any reference to my application in the stack trace.

Any idea?

---

Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.

[SPUserCodeSolutionExecutionFailedException: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.]

**Server stack trace:**

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeAppDomain.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxyForShim.ExecuteInternal(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcessProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

**Exception rethrown at [0]:**

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.ExecuteDelegate.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String currentAffinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodePoolableProcessConnection.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionHost.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinity, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

**Exception rethrown at [1]:**

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPUserCodeExecutionHostProxy.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, Guid siteCollectionId, SPUserToken userToken, String affinityBucketName, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeExecutionManager.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPSite site, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_9()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.ExecuteRequestInSandBox(HttpContext context, SPWeb web, SPWebPartManager manager, SPUserCodeWebPart userCodeWebPart)

**[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]**

Server stack trace:

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadContext.get_UserCodeContext()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadContext.get_Items()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadContext.Get(String key)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadContext.GetT

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.Dispose()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InvalidateRequest()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.Invalidate()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.Close()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Close()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Dispose()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite_SubsetProxy.Dispose__Inner()

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

**Exception rethrown at [0]:**

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite_SubsetProxy.Dispose()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Dispose__Inner()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Dispose()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartWrapper.Execute(SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.ExecuteWrapper(SPUserCodeWrapper wrapper, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

**Exception rethrown at [1]:**

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)

at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.CodeToExecuteWrapper.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)

at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeApplicationHostAppDomainRef.Execute(Type userCodeWrapperType, SPUserCodeCachedAssemblyGroup userAssemblyGroup, Guid siteCollectionId, Byte[] binaryUserCodeToken, Byte[] proxyOperationToken, SPUserCodeExecutionContext executionContext, Boolean shouldUsageLog, Int32 currentProcessId)

Comment: Can you post part of code? I think if sandbox solutions weren't enabled, you would get error informing you about this. And can you test something following: commenting out all the code that refers to SharePoint context, publish your solution, add webpart (which will most probably show nothing) and after that - uncomment your code and redeploy solution - I had some weird Null-pointer exception on SPContext.Current, when i was adding sandbox webpart to page, but when it was already on page - everything worked fine.

Comment: I think the actual code wouldn't help, its to complicated to show. But I have a try/catch around everything in the webpart which is not triggered? But I will try your suggestion!

Comment: I've just seen exactly the same error - did you have any luck with this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure as this is too long ago but make sure you release all objects related to SPSite, SPWeb etc (use "using") as this can cause this problem if I remember it right.

Answer (score 1):

Check if sandboxed solutions are enabled (correspoding service is running on your server). Also check if you are actually installing this solution as a sandboxed, not as a regular or vice versa.

Comment: Sandbox solutions are enabled, I have another webpart which works fine. And yes, it is installed as a sandboxed solution.